# jquery not firing from modal

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

The issue: this form will not submit.

(Inside Index which sits directly inside layout)

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalCategory" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">    
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmCategory" name="frmCategory">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Category Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Category Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDescription" cols="22"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" id="categorySubmit" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" value="OK" />
                </div>
            </form>    
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/ViewScripts/Admin/StoreAdmin.js"></script>    
}
```

Updated JS based on suggestions:

```
$("body").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
    //do your stuff here
    alert('foo1');
});

$("#modalCategory").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
    alert("foo2");
});

$(function () {    
    LoadActiveTab();

    function LoadActiveTab() {    
        var activeTab = $("#storeNav > li[class='active'] > a");
        LoadTabData(activeTab);    
    }

    function LoadTabData(container)
    {
        var hrefVal = $(container).attr("href");
        var $detailDiv = $(hrefVal);
        var url = $(container).data('url');

        $detailDiv.empty();

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $detailDiv.append(data);
        });
    }

    $(".btnStoreAdmin").on("click", function (evt) {    
        LoadTabData(this)    
    });

    //Product Categories
    $("#btnAddNew").on("click", function () {    
        ClearModal();
        $(".modal-title").append("<div class='h3'>Add Product Category</div>");    
    });

    function ClearModal() {
        $(".modal-title").empty();
        $('#frmCategory')[0].reset();
    }

    function BuildModal(modalId) {

    }

    $("#frmCategory").submit(function () {    
        var data = {    
            name: $("#txtName").val(),
            description: $("txtDescription").val()    
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/AddProductCategory',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                ClearModal();
                $("#modalCategory").toggle();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });    
    });

    $("body").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
        //do your stuff here
        alert('foo3');
    });

    $("#modalCategory").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
        alert("foo4");
    });
});
```

Things i've tried

1. moving the modal from a partial to the index page that hosts the partial
2. $("#frmCategory").on("submit", function()(){});
3. $("#categorySubmit").on("click", function()(){});
4. $(document).on("submit", "#frmCategory", function(){});
5. all variations inside and outside ready function
6. Moved my jquery bundles from the bottom to the top of the page.
7. Used both name, id and both as attributes on form

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the data-dismiss="modal" from your submit button and catch the event like this

```
$('body').on('submit', '#frmCategory',function () {
    //do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: In your question you didn't put your `js` in `<script></script>`. What about your original code? @Muckeypuck

Comment: add remove data-dismiss="modal" from the button (which was stopping it from firing) then your function to catch the event and ill accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit event to:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[name="frmCategory"]', (function () {
```

Another possible workaround is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="frmCategory" onsubmit="mySubmit(this)">
```

And add the global function:

```
function mySubmit(obj) {
  ....your code...
}
```

Comment: will edit, i tried id, name and both as attributes sorry

Comment: if nothing else works, i will use the global function work around which would probably work and mark that as accepted. Would like to try and figure this out though as it is. seems like fairly standard stuff (if thats stack overflow acceptable, not really an etiquette pro)

Answer (score 0):

You modal content is not in the DOM initially so you don't have the element.
You can try to add the submit event after you add the content to the modal (on success function).

Or something like `$('#yourmodal').on('submit', '#yourformid', function(){});`

And add the id to the form, currently you have just a class and a name...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
    //do your stuff here
    alert('foo1');
});

$("#modalCategory").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
    alert("foo2");
});

$(function () {

    LoadActiveTab();

    function LoadActiveTab() {

        var activeTab = $("#storeNav > li[class='active'] > a");
        LoadTabData(activeTab);

    }

    function LoadTabData(container)
    {
        var hrefVal = $(container).attr("href");
        var $detailDiv = $(hrefVal);
        var url = $(container).data('url');

        $detailDiv.empty();

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $detailDiv.append(data);
        });
    }

    $(".btnStoreAdmin").on("click", function (evt) {

        LoadTabData(this)

    });

    //Product Categories
    $("#btnAddNew").on("click", function () {

        ClearModal();
        $(".modal-title").append("<div class='h3'>Add Product Category</div>");

    });

    function ClearModal() {
        $(".modal-title").empty();
        $('#frmCategory')[0].reset();
    }

    function BuildModal(modalId) {

    }

    $("#frmCategory").submit(function () {

        var data = {

            name: $("#txtName").val(),
            description: $("txtDescription").val()

        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/AddProductCategory',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                ClearModal();
                $("#modalCategory").toggle();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });

    });

    $("body").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
        //do your stuff here
        alert('foo3');
    });

    $("#modalCategory").on("submit", "#frmCategory", function () {
        alert("foo4");
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalCategory" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmCategory" name="frmCategory">
                <div class="modal-body">


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Category Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Category Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDescription" cols="22"></textarea>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" id="categorySubmit" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" value="OK" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

First of all, the `$("#frmCategory")` does not match any element because there is no such element with ID `frmCategory`. Based on what you have now you should use `$("[name=frmCategory]").submit(function(){...})` instead.

Besides that, your scripts are not contained inside a `<script>` tag.

Another possibility is that if your modal is not present initially then your event handler will not attach to the form then you will need to use event delegation as suggested by @Azim's answer.

Comment: see updates. i readded as both name and id (as mentioned in original comments)

Comment: Please check the code snippets which works based on your current code without any modifications

Comment: Weird. any ideas why it wouldnt work from localhost?

Comment: Then did you get the form element when you type in `$("#frmCategory")` in the console?

Comment: yea and the other events in the script fire so im really confused

Comment: One way to check if the event listener attached correctly is to navigate to the form in Inspect element window and look at the event listeners under `Submit` event

Comment: i had to remove data-dismiss="modal" from the button and catch the event with azims answer. 

$('body').on('submit', '#frmCategory',function () {
    //do your stuff here
});

thanks for your help